# Can someone tell me what date format this is?

Tags: php, date, timestamp

I was reading documentation of an API and it uses this timestamp format:

2012-08-29T15:31:23Z

I have never seen one with T and Z positioned like that so I had to create a custom function to product this format.

Is there a built-in PHP method of producing a timestamp in this format or a standard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is universal time .... it is the date then a time separator and time is put into zulu time which is the same as UTC

You are able to do a simple `print strtotime('2012-08-29T15:31:23Z');` to change it to a unix timestamp

**[FROM W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime)**

> Example
>
> 1994-11-05T08:15:30-05:00 corresponds to November 5, 1994, 8:15:30 am, US Eastern Standard Time.
>
> 1994-11-05T13:15:30Z corresponds to the same instant.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, I change the date to use gmdate to conform.

Answer (score 1):

ISO 8601 date time format specifications

http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

"...
Examples

1994-11-05T08:15:30-05:00 corresponds to November 5, 1994, 8:15:30 am, US Eastern Standard Time.

1994-11-05T13:15:30Z corresponds to the same instant.

..."

Answer (score 0):

It's in the format standardized by [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). The `Z` is for the UTC timezone.

You can parse it with [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) and create your own with [date](http://php.net/date) (the DATE_ constant comes a list of [DateTime Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.types), which is linked from the *date* manpage):

```
$timestamp = strtotime('2012-08-29T15:31:23Z');
$datetime = date(DATE_ISO8601, $timestamp);
```