# Datetime conversion format in PHP

Tags: php, laravel

What method should I use to convert 2021-03-20T00:19:07.000000Z to 2021-03-20 00:19:07, in PHP and Laravel 8.x, by the way, If you can explain what does the T in the middle of 2021-03-20T00:19:07.000000Z and the dot behind each represent? I will very much appreciate you !!

Comment: It's called "zulu time". See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405087 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44206123 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181457

Answer (score 1):

You can use Carbon date library in php and laravel.

```
Carbon::parse('2021-03-20T00:19:07.000000Z')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input date is an [ISO 8601 formatted date](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

The `T` is the divider between date and time, so it is a static value.

To convert your ISO 8601 date to a `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` date format, you can easily use `DateTime` ([DateTime Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)).

So in your case the solution would be:

```
$input = '2021-03-20T00:19:07.000000Z';
$datetime = new DateTime(input);
$output = $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```